# Why when I delete a row in a tableview it deletes multiple rows?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm making a notes app and added the swipe to delete a row method. The problem I'm having is when there is multiple notes saved in the table view and I go to swipe one row to delete it deletes all the notes. Also when I quit the app and go back the notes are back in the table view. Heres the code I have:

```
class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {
    var notesItems: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        let userDefaults:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        let itemListFromUserDefaults:NSMutableArray? = userDefaults.objectForKey("itemList") as? NSMutableArray

        if ((itemListFromUserDefaults) != nil) {
            notesItems = itemListFromUserDefaults!
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
        self.navigationController?.toolbarHidden = false

        self.tableView.dataSource = self

        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
        UIToolbar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView?) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return notesItems.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        let notesItem:NSDictionary = notesItems.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary

        cell.textLabel?.text = notesItem.objectForKey("text") as? String

        return cell
    }

    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
            self.tableView.reloadData()

            self.tableView.beginUpdates()

            self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)

            // Delete the row from the data source
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code in `commitEditingStyle` is all wrong.

1. Don't reload the table view.
2. You must update the database before calling `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`.
3. You don't need to call `beginUpdates/endUpdated` to make one call to `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`.

You want:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
        // remove an object from notesItem for this index path

        self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    }
}
```

Comment: @maddy I get this error:Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (7) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (7), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

Comment: You are not updating the data source. Replace the comment in the code with actual code to update the data source.

Comment: I did it like this   notesItems.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)    and I get an error saying: NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

Comment: You need to make `notesItems` an `NSMutableArray` instead of an `NSArray`.

Comment: But you assign an `NSArray` to it from `NSUserDefaults`. Call `mutableCopy` on the array you get from `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x134e61600'

Comment: You left off the important part of that last error message. Make sure you are calling `mutableCopy` on the `NSArray` you are reading from `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: Where are you getting NSArray I dont see it in my code?

Comment: This line: `let itemListFromUserDefaults:NSMutableArray? = userDefaults.objectForKey("itemList") as? NSMutableArray`. Despite all of your uses of `NSMutableArray`, you are actually getting an `NSArray` from `NSUserDefaults`. Casting doesn't change what it really is.

Comment: Okay I called the mutableCopy and get no error but still get an error when I try to delete a row. Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
*** First throw call stack:
(libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92669/discussion-between-coding22-and-rmaddy).

Comment: Read the error. You still have an immutable array. You need a mutable array.

Comment: I did I put notesItems.mutableCopy(). Still get that error.

Comment: You need `notesItems = notesItems.mutableCopy()`.

Comment: Finaly works! I have one more problem, once it deletes it still shows up in the table view if I close the app and open it.

Comment: You need to persist that changes after you make them. Update `NSUserDefaults` with the updated array each time you update the array. BTW - don't use `NSUserDefaults` for data.

Comment: What do you suggest instead of NSUserDefaults, core data?